# Handling non-fatal errors in Java

Tags: java, error-handling

I've written a program to aid the user in configuring 'mechs for a game. I'm dealing with loading the user's saved data. This data can (and some times does) become partially corrupt (either due to bugs on my side or due to changes in the game data/rules from upstream).

I need to be able to handle this corruption and load as much as possible. To be more specific, the contents of the save file are syntactically correct but semantically corrupt. I can safely parse the file and drop whatever entries that are not semantically OK.

Currently my data parser will just show a modal dialog with an appropriate warning message. However displaying the warning is not the job of the parser and I'm looking for a way of passing this information to the caller.

Some code to show approximately what is going on (in reality there is a bit more going on than this, but this highlights the problem):

```
class Parser{
    public void parse(XMLNode aNode){
        ...
        if(corrupted) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Corrupted data found", 
                "error!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            // Keep calm and carry on
        }
    }
}

class UserData{
    static UserData loadFromFile(File aFile){
        UserData data = new UserData();
        Parser parser = new Parser();
        XMLDoc doc = fromXml(aFile);
        for(XMLNode entry : doc.allEntries()){
            data.append(parser.parse(entry));
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

The thing here is that bar an `IOException` or a syntax error in the XML, `loadFromFile` will always succeed in loading *something* and this is the wanted behavior. Somehow I just need to pass the information of what (if anything) went wrong to the caller. I could return a `Pair<UserData,String>` but this doesn't look very pretty. Throwing an exception will not work in this case obviously.

Does any one have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: `"Throwing an exception will not work in this case obviously."` -- why do you say this, as this may be just what you should do. You could create your own custom Exceptions classes for specific exceptions, passing into the exceptions the key info needed for the calling code, and in your catch blocks, handle the exception and notify the user. Maybe I'm reading your question wrong, but this seems exactly what exceptions are for -- to pass information about exceptional events up the program to a place that can handle it, and then notify the user.

Comment: Because it means that I don't get the partially loaded user data which is still valuable if I throw.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to represent, you can **use a class**, like [`SQLWarning`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLWarning.html) from the [java.sql](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) package.  When you have a `java.sql.Statement` and call `executeQuery` you get a `java.sql.ResultSet` and you can then call `getWarnings` on the result set directly, or even on the statement itself.

You can **use an enum**, like [`RefUpdate.Result`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/3.5.1.201410131835-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/RefUpdate.Result.html), from the [JGit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/documentation/) project.  When you have a `org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git` you can create a `FetchCommand`, which will provide you with a `FetchResult`, which will provide you with a collection of `TrackingRefUpdates`, which will each contain a `RefUpdate.Result` enum, which can be one of:

```
FAST_FORWARD
FORCED
IO_FAILURE
LOCK_FAILURE
NEW
NO_CHANGE
NOT_ATTEMPTED
REJECTED
REJECTED_CURRENT_BRANCH
RENAMED
```

In your case, you could even **use a boolean flag**:

```
class UserData {
    public boolean isCorrupt();
}
```

But since you mentioned there is a bit more than that going on in reality, it really depends on your model of "corrupt".  However, ***you will probably have more options*** if you have a `UserDataReader` that you can instantiate, instead of a static utility method.

Comment: The user data will have been forcibly regularised during the load so it will technically not be corrupt any more. But the user needs to know which entries were fixed so they can review them manually. I thought of returning a class with the result and warnings but thought it seemed a bit over engineered. I also considered an `ErrorReporter` type interface to pass to the load call.

Comment: It is common to use a result object containing the data and status of a read.  Whether or not it is over engineered depends on what the caller needs to know.  If it's only a yes or no question, go with the flag.  If it's a discrete outcome, use an enum.  If the caller needs more than that a result class can make your intent clearer.  But an `ErrorReporter` sounds like something you should only need if the warnings need to be broadcast as events.

Comment: It can be any number of discrete warnings.

Comment: Given what you've said about the data not technically being corrupt anymore, you might instead consider having a `List<DataCorrection>` in `UserData`, if what you are trying to do is show the caller what's been fixed, rather than what needs to be fixed.  `DataCorrection` can have the name and old value of the corrupt field.